# Search â€™, Â, � etc... How to fix strange encoding characters in python

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding

I tried to retrieve data from Google+ using API. When I wrote data into csv file, I observed weird and strange characters like ðŸ˜€ðŸ˜„ðŸ˜šðŸ˜‰ðŸ˜ â€™
After googling, I concluded this is an encoding issue.

To write retrieved data in a file, I used the following code:

```
file = open('filename, 'a', encoding='utf-8')
writer = csv.writer(file)
writer.writerow(values)
```

To check my terminal encoding, I used

```
import sys
sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

Output is: utf-8

Don't know where is the problem?

Comment: Perhaps you need `file = open(filename, 'a', encoding='latin-1')`

Comment: I am getting the error using encoding='latin-1 ' as :writer.writerow(values)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 55-56: ordinal not in range(256)

Comment: I don't think your system's default coding will help. You need to check the coding used in the Google API. Perhaps, you could specify which API is being used?

Comment: I used Google+ API, https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth

Comment: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/ref_encoding.  I don't think: issue is related to Google+ API encoding.

Comment: If someone looking for the same problem, I would suggest changing the text editor. In my case, I switched to 'Atom'

Answer (score 1):

Your [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) appears overmuch *minimal* to be *complete and verifiable*. In any case, it looks like ***double*** [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake):

```
value = "â€˜ðŸ˜€ðŸ˜„ðŸ˜šðŸ˜‰ðŸ˜ â€™" ### gathered from the question
print(value.encode('cp1252','backslashreplace').decode('utf-8','backslashreplace'))
```

> ```
> ‘’
> ```