# Reliably clean/convert all unicode/emojis for JSON parsing

Tags: python, json, jsonparser

I'm seeking the correct sequence of Python `decode()` and `encode()` functions required to result in completely clean and parse-able JSON, no matter which combinations of unusual ASCII/unicode/emoji characters present.

In Javascript, I'm trying to `JSON.parse()` some API data returned from my Python backend. My first hurdle was this entry:

> ðŸ”¥My name is Miguel Ive been in the flooring industry since 2014, on
> 2018 I started my own flooring store and our priority is provide the
> best customer service to our clients ! Visit us on our new showroom on
> woods cross we will be happy to help you with your project and we will
> give you a free in home consultation and ask about our 10%discount on
> same day booking ! ðŸ”¥

I successfully used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65384920/3511695) to decode such characters on the Python backend:

```
value.encode('cp1252','backslashreplace').decode('utf-8','backslashreplace')
```

Result:

> My name is Miguel Ive been in the flooring industry since 2014, on
> 2018 I started my own flooring store and our priority is provide the
> best customer service to our clients  ! Visit us on our new showroom
> on woods cross we will be happy to help you with your project and we
> will give you a free in home consultation and ask about our
> 10%discount on same day booking !

But then I ran into new API calls with JSON that `JSON.parse()` threw errors for. For example, these `\x92` characters were preventing the JSON from correctly parsing ("`Bad escaped character`"):

> Hello, I\x92m Eric, I\x92ve been around all phases of
> construction since I was old enough to hold a hammer. Was taught by my
> father how to do it right the first time, and make it so people can
> afford to do more with their budget. I can do it all, but enjoy doing
> flooring and tile work. I\x92m not afraid of a creative challenge

So I reluctantly (since I knew it wouldn't be a reliable solution) added a simple `replace()` statement:

```
decoded_text.replace('\\x92', "’")
```

But I (expectedly) soon ran into new API calls that returned data that `JSON.parse()` refused to work with, like `\u011f\x9f\x91\x8c\u011f\x9f\ufffd\xbd` in the string below:

> Went and above and beyond to expose and fix other poorly done
> installations \u011f\x9f\x91\x8c\u011f\x9f\ufffd\xbd

Here is my full Python code for calling the API, and my attempt at properly decoding it:

```
# models/api_connector.py
from odoo import models, fields, api
import requests
import base64
import configparser
import os
    
class MyAPIConnector(models.Model):
    _name = 'api.connector'
    _description = 'API Connector'

    name = fields.Char('Name')

    def _generate_auth_header(self):
        # Read configuration
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'config.ini')
        config.read(config_path)
        # Combine and encode credentials
        org_name = config.get('api_credentials', 'org_name')
        secret_key = config.get('api_credentials', 'secret_key')
        combined_credentials = f"{org_name}:{secret_key}"
        encoded_credentials = base64.b64encode(combined_credentials.encode()).decode()
        return f"Basic {encoded_credentials}"

    def fetch_data(self, zip_code):
        try:
            headers = {'Authorization': self._generate_auth_header()}
            category_pk = '123456789'
            API_ENDPOINT = f"https://api.myapi.com/v1/partners/discoverylite/pros?zip_code={zip_code}&category_pk={category_pk}&utm_source=myCompany"
            response = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, headers=headers)
            response_text = response.text

            # Decoding and re-encoding the response text
            decoded_text = response_text.encode('cp1252', 'backslashreplace').decode('utf-8', 'backslashreplace')

            decoded_text = decoded_text.replace('\\x92', "’")

            return decoded_text
        except Exception as e:
            _logger.error(f"Error: {e}")
```

Here is the **raw, untouched** data returned from the API for the latest problematic entry (which `JSON.parse()` parses just fine but contains encoded characters):

```
{
    "results": [{
        "service_id": "490803031657299972",
        "business_name": "Jay Contractors LLC",
        "rating": 4.972222222222222,
        "num_reviews": 36,
        "years_in_business": 1,
        "num_hires": 87,
        "thumbtack_url": "https://www.thumbtack.com/pa/lansdowne/handyman/jay-contractors-llc/service/490803031657299972?category_pk=151436204227846419\u0026utm_medium=partnership\u0026utm_source=cma-hewn\u0026zip_code=19701",
        "image_url": "https://production-next-images-cdn.thumbtack.com/i/490934068026425349/desktop/standard/thumb",
        "background_image_url": "https://production-next-images-cdn.thumbtack.com/i/319588452476190788/small/standard/hero",
        "featured_review": "Went and above and beyond to expose and fix other poorly done installations ğŸ‘ŒğŸ�½",
        "quote": {
            "starting_cost": 5000,
            "cost_unit": "on-site estimate"
        },
        "introduction": "My focus is quality, and dedication to the job. I take pride in every job, from start to finish. Always go for 100% satisfaction by client and see them smiling after the work is completed.\n\nPlease keep in mind if your using the instant book feature, it means your hiring me for my services and if you decide to cancel later on there will be a charge.\n\nAccept Cash, Cashapp, Zelle, and Venmo.\nNo Checks please.\n\nLicensed and Insured",
        "pills": ["popular", "licensed"],
        "location": "Bear, DE",
        "similar_jobs_done": 1,
        "license_verified": true,
        "num_of_employees": 2,
        "has_background_check": true,
        "iframe_url": ""
    }]
}
```

And here is that same entry's JSON after being processed my Python's decoding functions, which `JSON.parse()` refuses to parse (with the error `SyntaxError: Bad escaped character in JSON at ... JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`):

```
{
    "results": [{
        "service_id": "490803031657299972",
        "business_name": "Jay Contractors LLC",
        "rating": 4.972222222222222,
        "num_reviews": 36,
        "years_in_business": 1,
        "num_hires": 87,
        "thumbtack_url": "https://www.thumbtack.com/pa/lansdowne/handyman/jay-contractors-llc/service/490803031657299972?category_pk=151436204227846419\u0026utm_medium=partnership\u0026utm_source=cma-hewn\u0026zip_code=19701",
        "image_url": "https://production-next-images-cdn.thumbtack.com/i/490934068026425349/desktop/standard/thumb",
        "background_image_url": "https://production-next-images-cdn.thumbtack.com/i/319588452476190788/small/standard/hero",
        "featured_review": "Went and above and beyond to expose and fix other poorly done installations \u011f\x9f\x91\x8c\u011f\x9f\ufffd\xbd",
        "quote": {
            "starting_cost": 5000,
            "cost_unit": "on-site estimate"
        },
        "introduction": "My focus is quality, and dedication to the job. I take pride in every job, from start to finish. Always go for 100% satisfaction by client and see them smiling after the work is completed.\n\nPlease keep in mind if your using the instant book feature, it means your hiring me for my services and if you decide to cancel later on there will be a charge.\n\nAccept Cash, Cashapp, Zelle, and Venmo.\nNo Checks please.\n\nLicensed and Insured",
        "pills": ["popular", "licensed"],
        "location": "Bear, DE",
        "similar_jobs_done": 1,
        "license_verified": true,
        "num_of_employees": 2,
        "has_background_check": true,
        "iframe_url": ""
    }]
}
```

Comment: If the JSON is invalid in the first place, there is no sane solution. Sounds like the original probably had `\u0092` and it got converted to `\x92` though? Without seeing your original JSON, we can only speculate.

Comment: `\ufffd` is unambiguously a sign that something went wrong earlier in the pipeline. This reinforces the impression that your input may not be well-formed.

Comment: The original API response, and my decoded version of it, is in the OP. The original API response of the problematic JSON in question contains the characters `ğŸ‘ŒğŸ�½`, which got converted to `\u011f\x9f\x91\x8c\u011f\x9f\ufffd\xbd` via my Python's `response_text.encode('cp1252', 'backslashreplace').decode('utf-8', 'backslashreplace')`. Now I suppose I need to convert `\u011f\x9f\x91\x8c\u011f\x9f\ufffd\xbd` to the correct emojis(?) so that `JSON.parse()` doesn't complain about it, or find a more reliable Python library to convert the original characters in a single step

Comment: Then if the original bytes were valid, your mangling mangled them; again, we can't know what the original bytes before mangling were without a hex dump or etc. Perhaps see [the Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/chararcter-encoding/info)

Comment: What does `response.json()` give you?  And if that looks bad, `response.content` is the undecoded bytes object.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thanks! I think response.content is exactly what i needed! Emojis/unicode and newlines are all preserved

Comment: Realize that .content is raw bytes. .json() should correctly decode it, unless the serving website mis-documents the correct encoding.